# Can i see the changes made in the files just `git add`'ed?

Tags: git

When i do some work in working directory, i can use `git diff` to see what changes I have made.

Now i just ran `git add` for the files newly modified and created but not yet `git commit`, `git diff` doesn't show any thing. Is it still possible to see what changes have been made which were just `git add`'ed?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `git diff --cached`

Answer (score 2):

Use `git diff --staged` to look at the diff for staged files.  `git diff` only looks at unstaged files by default.